# Delphi - Easy way to convert QuickReport into a Rave report instead of recreating it from scratch

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports, quickreports

I am currently using rave but I have a few highly detailed reports which were made using QuickReports. I need to add these QuickReports to my Rave project. Is there an easy way to do this instead of creating them from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Rave reports are a completely diffent approach to reporting compared to QR, since it's an reporting IDE INSIDE Deplhi/CB. And also an reporting script language based on Object Pascal.

QR uses forms and components in the Rad Studio IDE. All are programmed from the Delphi IDE. 
I used QR very few times, but Rave I used extensively. It's another world, going from QR to Rave is kinda like to go from pure C to Visual Basic.Net.

TL;DR: Rave is almost an third language on Rad Studio. IMHO there's no way to auto-convert an QR (which is just an form with components) to Rave (which is almost an application inside the application).